# Bearer from Azure request missing

Tags: azure, authentication, botframework, bearer-token, mashery

I'm facing an issue of communication from Azure to Mashery (and so Mashery to my code but it's work).
I'm in a professional Azure environment.
From a user's request, Azure has to send his request to our program in my company's cloud (thanks to the messaging endpoint of the bot azure). However for security, Azure has to send it through Mashery.

In consequence my code needs to receive users' requests with a security layer using Mashery : Azure has to be authenticated by Mashery.

It's required to work properly with the SDK. The SDK requires a bearer in the header of the message. However there is no bearer currently.

How can I setup Azure to authenticate itself to Mashery (before sending the user's request at the messaging endpoint) ?

Comment: Are you using a channel for your bot or are you using Directline?

Comment: I'm using Skype for Business (I know it will be deprecated soon). But this link from Azure to Skype For Business works. This is the link from Azure to Mashery which is interesting in my case. I can use Mashery as token provider for Azure (then to be able to use my API in the other side of Mashery) ?